# R + PostgreSQL with config file

Tags: r, postgresql, shiny, config

With RMySQL + rstudio/pool you can do this:

```
pool <- dbPool(
  drv = RMySQL::MySQL(),
  dbname = "databait",
  group = "databait-group"
)
```

Where the databait group refers to a .my.cnf file in your home (~) folder that might look something like this:

```
[databait-group]
user=bait
pass="1234"
port=3306
host=127.0.0.1
```

This way, RMySQL will automatically get host and password from .my.cnf and connect to the desired database; **without having to save the password in the code**. Which is great.

How can I do this for PostgreSQL?